# Add -j 4 command to eclipse build

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I am building an android NativeActivity in eclipse using the ndk.

When I do it from the command line ndk-build -j 4 it goes much faster than when I don't add -j 4.

But I like how eclipse points me to compile errors in code. Is there a way I can have eclipse invoke ndk-build using -j 4?

Comment: What errors do you get? Where did you put the `-j` parameter?

Comment: No errors. Just don't no where to put it. So I have never ran with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the Project Properties. Go to **C/C++ Build / Builder** and uncheck **Use default build command**. Then below you can enter your custom `ndk-build -j4` command with additonal parameters.

Answer (score 0):

While changing the **default build command** has the work done, it may be safer to keep the command as default, and only modify the "behavior", as shown in the screenshot:

[image: C/C++ Build properties]